# TextView does not display with HoloDark

Tags: android, android-layout

I am having a pretty serious issues of my textview not displaying when using the HoloDark theme. When looking at it up close, I can see that it is faded and exists, but does not display correctly. Can someone shed a little light? Thanks in advance.

```
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:id="@+id/txtMessage"
    android:textSize="45sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:gravity="center|top"
    android:textColor="#02ffffff"
    android:textColorHint="#02ffffff"
    android:textColorHighlight="#02ffffff"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:text="#02ffffff"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColorLink="#01ffffff"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:layout_below="@+id/prgBarBlue"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
android:textColor="#02ffffff"
```

the "02" before text color makes it almost invisible. Are you sure that's how you want it?

Comment: thanks! I switched it to another color for test and it worked.

Comment: @jpavlov, just to clarify you can put just #FFFFFF to get full white color with 0 transparency. When you put another 2 characters in front of it, it controls the transparency from 00 (full transparent) to FF (no transparency). In your case the 02 made it almost fully transparent.